# Modal image issue (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an image clickable.

I'm getting an error saying 'syntax error, unexpected '<''

```
<img border="0" alt="img1" src="<img src='./assets/workImages/".$row['image1']."'>" width="100" height="100">
```

I've tried writing it a few ways but always seem to come with an error of some sort.

The fact that I have to use a file path and a PHP variable is whats making this look more confusing to me than it probably is.

Very very new to PHP so forgive any blatant stupidity, if any.

Comment: Sorry, left out the href, still doesn't work without it of course.

Comment: Is that written inside a PHP block (`<?php` and `?>` ) or outside in a plain HTML block? You also have an image tag as source inside an image tag? What does `$row['image1']` contain? Image name or image data?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you are doing this in html and then breaking in to your PHP to just echo out the $row value, or if you're echoing all of the html from inside PHP, which leads to two different solutions.

Solution 1 (this is HTML and you need to echo your php):

```
<img border="0" alt="img1" src="/assets/workImages/<?= $row['image1'];?>" width="100" height="100">
```

Solution 2 (We're echoing all of this from PHP):

```
echo '<img border="0" alt="img1" src="/assets/workImages/'.$row['image1'].'" width="100" height="100">';
```

Comment: My apologies. Should've made that clear. Echoing from PHP, worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If you wouldn't mind marking this as the answer to the question I would really appreciate it.